# Does mysql check integrity of the physical file

Tags: mysql, database, security

I know that mysql does not encrypt its files, thus it should be possible to edit said files. But my question is: assuming a malicious user did, would the mysql database detect it and see that the file integrity has been violated or would it go on as nothing has happened. Or a third option do i manually have to check the integrity myself once in a while.

Comment: Check the integrity of what? Which file? What are you testing for here? Which database engine are you using, InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @tadman Sorry for my ignorance, the engine is InnoDB and the files I refer to is what mysql stores on your disk. I don't know exactly which files you would need to edit I am only asking if it is possible. 
For instance lets assume I have a table called users, can a malicious user go and add himself as an admin(giving he had access to my disk) in my users table. Or does mysql check the integrity(Of the database files on the disk) either through a checksum or some other means.

Comment: @JannickJohnsen It isn't possible in the first place even with administrative access. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can only detect corrupted databases, not those that have been altered. It is impossible to know for sure if the database has been altered, that's not something people generally worry about. If the database is *structurally* sound, MySQL will use it. If not, and you're using a journaled database like InnoDB, it will try to recover it.

If someone has sufficient access to your system, physical, network or otherwise, that they might alter the users table your system is not secure. Period.

If you're asking from the perspective of a forensic audit, that is way beyond the scope of Stack Overflow and I highly advise to you hire a **trained professional**.